# How to delete 2 tables at once

Tags: mysql

I want to delete 2 tables records at once using WHERE department = 'something'

I try this and it did not work :

```
DELETE FROM departments, categories 
WHERE department.department = 'something' 
AND categories.department = 'something';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using this statement :

> DELETE departments . * , categories . *  FROM departments,categories 
>   WHERE departments.department = '{$dept_name}'  AND
>   categories.department = '{$dept_name}'

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM departments INNER JOIN categories
    WHERE departments.department = categories.department 
        and department.department = 'something'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM departments
JOIN categories ON departments.department = categories.department
WHERE department.department = 'something'`
```